# Clone + Rename file with PHP

Tags: php, file, rename

how do I clone and rename a file with php.

I need to take.

thumb_123.jpg

Copy it.

Rename it to thumb_456.jpg

I can do the renaming just fine with `rename()`. Its the copying that I don't get.

Comment: couple of Q&As to check: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=copy+file+[php]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`copy('thumb_123.jpg','thumb_456.jpg')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)

Comment: Hurray for the easy-to-find PHP documentation.

Comment: i came here after reading the documentation, wish it was said that we can give it a different filename when copying. Thanks for the clarification Mark!