# Copy & rename a file to the same directory without deleting the original file

Tags: php, file, file-upload, file-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clone + Rename file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245369/clone-rename-file-with-php)

This should be pretty easy.  I wan't to copy  & rename images that already exist on the server *while still retaining the original image*.

Here's the original image location:

```
images/
   folder/
       one.jpg
```

This is what I want:

```
images/
   folder/
       one.jpg 
       one_thumb.jpg
```

How can I achieve this?  You can see I'm not just simply renaming an existing file / image.  I want to copy it and rename it to the same directory.

Comment: This looks like just copying. What is being renamed exactly?

Comment: Copy it with [`copy()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php). Easy peasy.

Comment: with php's copy function maybe ....

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php was the first result for "copy file php". Stop being lazy.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Just use the copy method: http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Ex:

```
<?php
$file = 'images/folder/one.jpg';
$newfile = 'Images/folder/one_thumb.jpg';

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "failed to copy";
}
```

Answer (score 9):

PHP has a function, [copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) built-in that can do this. Here's an example:

```
<?php
$file = 'one.jpg';
$newfile = 'one_thumb.jpg';

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
}
?>
```

The function returns a boolean indicating whether the copy was successful. It's as simple as that!